# Flexbox - item is not centered if content is not long enough

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like my page to be displayed like this:

[image: I would like it to be displayed like this]

The pink and brown boxes should be 50% of the green

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/termitek12/h1az7ws8/)

```css
.container
{margin:10px;
padding:10px;
border-radius:10px;
background:aqua;}

.green
{padding:10px;
background:green;}

.blue
{text-align:center;
background:blue;}

.violet
{background:violet;}

.pink
{padding:10px;
display:inline-flex;
flex:1 0 100%;
flex-flow:row wrap;
background:pink;}

.cornflowerblue
{display:flex;
justify-content:center;
flex:1 0 100%;
flex-flow:row wrap;
align-items:stretch;
background:cornflowerblue;}

.yellow
{width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
background:yellow;}

.brown
{padding:10px;
display:inline-flex;
flex:1 0 100%;
flex-flow:row wrap;
background:brown;}

.red
{display:flex;
justify-content:center;
flex:1 0 100%;
flex-flow:row wrap;
align-items:stretch;
background:red;}

.orange
{width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
background:orange;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="green">
        <div class="blue">center</div>
        <div class="violet">left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pink">
        <div class="cornflowerblue">center</div>
        <div class="yellow">left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="brown">
        <div class="red">center</div>
        <div class="orange">left</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please familiarize yourself with [what's considered on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question as it stands is currently **off-topic**: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*

Comment: code is in q content. Image is for better understanding.

Comment: A link to an external resource is not considered *in the question itself*. You even put spaces in your link instead of periods so that you could circumvent the rule about posting JSFiddle links. There's a reason the rule exists...

Comment: ahh ok, it doesn't matter for me but if you want code here in question, no problem. I thought all persons interested in will follow fiddle anyway.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? ... http://jsfiddle.net/h1az7ws8/2/ ... and if not, you need to be more specific with your problem description

Comment: And for the record, SO users is not interested in follow external links. SO is a QA site where the value is to have both code and explanation within the question, as if not, what will happen when that fiddle suddenly is dead? ... That means this question will have no value for future users

Comment: @LGson nope - display: inline-block; doesn't fix this. pink and brown need to be 50%. About external links, yea point taken but fiddle won't be dead, SO could go down too, it's just faster to edit the code it self.

Comment: Your item is being centered correctly (text-alignment wise, that is). What do you mean by you want it to be centered?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/termitek12/h1az7ws8/5/ - those two boxes - (pink and brown should be 50% of the green).

Answer (score 0):

The basics to get that layout is to make `container` a flex container, and then assign a flex-basis value to each `green` (flex-basis: 100%), `pink`/`brown` (flex-basis: 50%)

*I also cleaned up the CSS some, so now you have a slim code rendering the layout you asked for*

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1az7ws8/7/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.green {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
}
  .blue {
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
  }
  .violet {
    background: violet;
  }

.pink {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: pink;
}
  .cornflowerblue {
    text-align: center;
    background: cornflowerblue;
  }
  .yellow {
    background: yellow;
  }

.brown {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: brown;
}
  .red {
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
  }
  .orange {
    background: orange;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">
    <div class="blue">center</div>
    <div class="violet">left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pink">
    <div class="cornflowerblue">center</div>
    <div class="yellow">left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="brown">
    <div class="red">center</div>
    <div class="orange">left</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested it through, and I'm impressed. Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. CSS was copied from minified file.

Comment: @termitek12 To accept you don't need 15 rep., just click the gray check mark to the left of my answer. When done it will turn green. Btw, the 15 rep is to be able to vote